# Push duplicate query parameters to Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to construct a url string like so "http://localhost:64549/request/list?page=1&dataLakeStatus=1&dataLakeStatus=2" with duplicate keys in the query parameters. How can I do this with Vue router, since JS doesn't allow for duplicate keys?

```js
 private redirectToFirstPage() {
    const query = { page: this.currentPage.toString(), dataLakeStatus: '1', dataLakeStatus: '2' };
    this.$router.push({ query });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private redirectToFirstPage() {
    const query = {
        page: this.currentPage.toString(),
        dataLakeStatus: [1, 2]
    };

    this.$router.push({ query });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<router-link :to="doubleQuery">Double<router-link>
```

and in you computed method

```
computed: {
  doubleQuery() {
    return `${this.$route.path}?dataLakeStatus=1&dataLakeStatus=2`
  }
}
```